# unreachable code detected in loop

Tags: java, eclipse

Why am i getting unreachable code detected on 'b' in the else loop?

```
private void a1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;

        if (true)
        {
            b.Text = "X";
        }
        else
        {
            b.Text = "O";
        }
        turn = !turn;

    }
```

Comment: Because your `if` condition is always evaluating to `true`.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you meant to write:

```
private void a1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;

    if (turn)
    {
        b.Text = "X";
    }
    else
    {
        b.Text = "O";
    }
    turn = !turn;

}
```

As was said, the `if(true)` block will always be evaluated, leaving the `else` block unreachable.

**Note:** Just a note here, this would be where I would use the ternary operator (As long as the conventions you're following allow you to. [The usage of the operator should be consistent]).

You would get `b.Text = turn ? "X" : "O"` instead of the `if/else` block. You can also declare "X" and "O" as constants in static final variables to allow improve readability and make modifications easier.

Comment: what is turn? I don't see it defined.

Comment: It's at the bottom, but it's not part of the function. We don't even know what it does.

Comment: It's pretty clear this is some kind of tic-tac-toe program, and he's trying to flip a square on each click

Answer (score 1):

`else` part will never be reached because compiler already knows that first condition `if(true)` will always be executed.

#### In java any un-reachable code results into compilation error.

It's better explained under [JLS§14.21. Unreachable Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)

> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because it is unreachable.

compiler is so smart in this case if you convert it into below code then it will never give you this error

```
boolean flag = true
if(flag){
    b.Text = "X";
}else{
    b.Text = "O";
}
```

Now try this one:

```
int x=5;
if (false) { x=3; } // same Dead code
```

---

### Can I post extra examples? - asking from Down-voter

There are lot more explained in above JLS section.

Here is an example:

```
while(true){
   System.out.println("hello");
}
System.out.println("bye"); // this line is in problem
```

Now use same flag but make it `final`

```
final boolean flag = true;
while(flag ){
   System.out.println("hello");
}
System.out.println("bye"); // still this line is in problem
// because compiler knows that final variable never be changed once assigned
```

Comment: Then what should i use over here?

Comment: declare a boolean variable and assign it to true. this should resolve your problem. That way the compiler won't evaluate the if statement at compile time, instead it will do so on run time

Answer (score 0):

The JVM already evaluated your code at compile time and knew that the else part will never be rearched